# How to Build one form with input of many views

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have 3 tables/models:

Customer 
Address 
City

Each one have their views,but I need to add Address and City to the Customer view and there will be all the inputs from each view and it will result in only one Form. I read some stuff about include these views in Customer's view using elements.

What is the best way for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading you right, you have 3 tables, customer, address & city, and want to read them all when you have a user view?

Sounds like you want to set up [A CakePHP association](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html), likely a hasOne relationship.

**Edit:** [Here's how you'd use an element](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements) to accomplish this:

```
// Form
<?php echo $this->element('cityselect'); ?>

// app/View/Elements/cityselect.ctp
<?php $cities = $this->requestAction('/cities/index'); ?>
// Use $cities to populate element form
```

You'll probably want to write an action for your cities/address controllers that returns key-pairs to easily populate your [select](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3aselect) field.